# How can I create a loop for setInterval in React?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I am working on a breathe cycle application, and I want to create a simple cycle for this two situation: breathe in / breathe out.
At the beginning, I have a message and it shows 'breathe in' state, then I change the state after 5 seconds as 'breathe out' with setInterval.
The point where I have stuck is, it stops after this step. It should continue as breathe in / breathe out.

I am new in React, is setInterval correct method for doing this?

```
  function App() {

  const [message, setMessage] = useState('breathe in');

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setMessage('breathe out');
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="circle">
        <span>{message}</span> 
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your setMessage line and you are good to go.

```
setMessage(message === 'breathe in' ? 'breathe out' : 'breathe in');
```

Comment: I'd like to complement, you should use `setMessage(message => message === 'breathe in' ? 'breathe out' : 'breathe in')` with 5sec cooldown you should not have a problem anyway

Comment: Indeed its a complement but can't avoid already declared variable warning. I suggest to change the name as well `setMessage(msg => msg === 'breathe in' ? 'breathe out' : 'breathe in')`